# Code analysis doesn't work in subdirectories of the source folder

Tags: pydev

I'm working with a Python-Project with several subdirectories within the source folder.
The code analysis seems to work only on scripts directly in the src folder. All scripts in subfolders are not analyzed.

I have added the top-level source folder to the PYTHONPATH. Is it necessary to add all subdirectories as well? I'm using Eclipse Indigo with PyDev 2.4.0.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your file is beneath the PYTHONPATH but not under a python package (i.e.: a python package is a folder that has an `__init__.py` file in it -- note that all the folders up to your module need to have that `__init__.py` file) or your folder is not a valid python name (in which case it's also not treated as a package -- i.e.: folders with '.', '-', etc in the name).

If that's not the case, please post a snapshot of the PyDev package explorer.

(as a general rule, subdirectories of a source folder shouldn't be set as source folders... although you can do to support some exceptional use-cases)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's right, the scripts are not under python packages. Because I use the PyDev project as a testsuite, in that all testscripts are contained in specific subfolders. So it seems that I really have to add all these subfolders to the PYTHONPATH, isn't it? Or are there any other/better solutions to realize a testsuite with PyDev? Best regards!

Comment: Particularly I just put the tests in a test dir below each package and when deploying I just remove those test packages. You could also let all the tests in a different source folder (i.e. pythonpath entry) or a separate project altogether.

Comment: Finally I found the problem: my directory names contained spaces. I didn't know that spaces aren't allowed for valid python paths. After renaiming these folders the code analysis worked fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Spaces are not allowed because you wouldn't be able to import that module from Python itself (i.e.: "import my module" wouldn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Your files need not to be in `PYTHONPATH` to be code-analyzed，at least this is true for my PyDev 2.6.0.

I only add my project(not packages) root dir to `PYTHONPATH` in project properties, and the files in subdirectories are analyzed.

Be be sure to check the dir names and python file names. They must be valid [python identifier](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) for it to be imported to be analyzed. It cannot contain some innocent-looking characters, like dot and dash.